How to number an array?
I have an array like this : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a' ]
I want to obtain this : [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]
The idea is to give the first value of the arr1 array 0 value, the second 1, etc...
I tried this :
function onlyUnique(value, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) === index;
}
let arr1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a' ]
var arr1_uniq= arr1.filter(onlyUnique);
let k=0
var list = []
for (let i in arr1_uniq){
    list.push(k)
    k++
}

So I have the arr1 without duplicate : ['a', 'b', 'c']
And the corresponding values : [0, 1, 2]
And finally I tried to use the findIndex function to reallocate arr1 values but I have issues.

What did you try and what didn't work as expected?

Could you clarify how you are trying to number the array? Are you trying to map a=0, b=1... z=25? Or are you trying to create an array of indicies? Like, if 'b' came first in the array, would b=0?

Could do with some more samples or less-associative example, eg ['a','a','z','f','a'] -> [0, 1, 2]

['a','a','z','f','a'].map(x => x.charCodeAt(0) - 97)

Here is the desired code sample using Map:
function mapToIndexes(arr) {
    const map = new Map();
    return arr.map((item, index) => {
        if (!map.has(item)) {
            map.set(item, map.size);
        }
        return map.get(item);
    });
}

const arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
const result = mapToIndexes(arr);
console.log(result); // Output: [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]


Hi, thanks a lot for your help
Have a nice day !

It should be possible by mapping the values to its unique index like this:


function indexMapper(arr) {
    const uniqueValues = [...new Set(arr)];
    const inverseMap = Object.fromEntries(uniqueValues.map((val, index) => [val, index]));
    return arr.map(value => inverseMap[value]);
}

// Example usage
let arr1 = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
let result = indexMapper(arr1);
console.log(result);  // [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]




Hi, Thanks for your help !

You can use a Map<Object, Number> and a counter to keep track of the indices.


const indexArray = (arr) => {
  const lookup = new Map();
  let currIndex = 0;
  return arr.map((item) => {
    if (lookup.has(item)) return lookup.get(item);
    lookup.set(item, currIndex);
    return currIndex++;
  });
};

const arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
const res = indexArray(arr);

console.log(...res); // [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]



You can remove the need for the currIndex if you utilize the size property of the map.


const indexArray = (arr) => {
  const lookup = new Map();
  return arr.map((item) => {
    if (!lookup.has(item)) {
      lookup.set(item, lookup.size);
    }
    return lookup.get(item);
  });
};

const arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
const res = indexArray(arr);

console.log(...res); // [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]



Here it is in one line:


const indexArray = (arr) =>
  (lookup =>
    arr.map((item) =>
      (lookup.has(item)
        ? lookup
        : lookup.set(item, lookup.size)
      ).get(item)))
  (new Map());

const arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];
const res = indexArray(arr);

console.log(...res); // [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]



And now, the code golf:


// 64 bytes
f=a=>(m=>a.map(e=>(m.has(e)?m:m.set(e,m.size)).get(e)))(new Map)

console.log(...f(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a'])) // [0, 0, 1, 2, 0]



